# React Native jpg file upload to Parse.com

Tags: cordova, parse-platform, react-native

I am implementing a React Native app that uses react-native-file-transfer to upload jpeg files to Parse.com.  I chose this library because it implements the file transfer via Object-C and so has performance advantages over implementing the transfer in React Native (i.e. avoids transferring data over the React-Native / iOS bridge).

The file that I'm uploading is a known good jpeg file, but when I upload it using react-native-file-transfer, it adds the following prefix to the beginning of the file:

> ------react.file.transfer.form.boundary Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="proposalPhoto.jpg" Content-Length:
>   22308

I believe the prefix is added because react-native-file-transfer uses Cordova multi-part. When I try to open the uploaded jpeg file, it is no longer recognized as a JPEG file (and can't be opened).  If I use a hex file editor and remove the prefix, the file is once again recognized as a proper JPEG file.

Does anyone have any suggestion for uploading a JPEG file to parse.com without making the resulting JPEG file unreadable or taking the performance hit of doing the upload directly in React Native?

Btw, here's the code that I implemented using react-native-file transfer...

```
uploadPhotoToParse( photoPath ) {

    var headers = {
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': CONFIG.PARSE_APP_ID,
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': CONFIG.PARSE_REST_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg2'
    } 
    var data = {};

    photoURL="/Users/wookiem/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Simulator/446F37B1-477B-4492-B2B8-8C8FE33327DF/data/Containers/Data/Application/1B1B2449-42F1-40FB-85ED-4781CC68E191/Documents/logo.jpg"

    var obj = {
            uri: 'file://' + photoPath,
            uploadUrl: 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/pic.jpg',
            fileName: 'proposalPhoto.jpg',
            mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
            headers: headers,
            data: data
    };  

    NativeModules.FileTransfer.upload(obj, (err, res) => {
            console.log(res);   
    });
}
```

Update #2 -- Using fetch method, attempting to upload raw jpeg file.

This results in a zero-byte file being uploaded.  Here is my code:

```
uploadPhotoToParse() {

    photoURL="file:///Users/wookiem/logo.jpg"

    fetch('https://api.parse.com/1/files/pic.jpg',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'X-Parse-Application-Id': CONFIG.PARSE_APP_ID,
                'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': CONFIG.PARSE_REST_API_KEY,
                'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
            },
            url: photoURL
        }
    ).then((response) => {
        if ((response.status === 200 || response.status === 201)) {
            return {};
        } else {
            var res = JSON.parse(response._bodyInit);
            throw (res);
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        throw(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working by using a separate fork of react-native-file-upload that added support for raw file uploads:

https://github.com/rebe1one/react-native-file-transfer.git

The npm version of react-native-file-upload is limited to multi-part file uploads which breaks the jpeg file convention when uploading to Parse.com.

Here's the code I used:

```
uploadPhotoToParse( photoPath ) {

    var headers = {
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': CONFIG.PARSE_APP_ID,
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': CONFIG.PARSE_REST_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg2'
    } 
    var data = {};

    var obj = {
            uri: 'file://' + photoPath,
            uploadUrl: 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/pic.jpg',
            fileName: 'proposalPhoto.jpg',
            contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
            mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
            headers: headers,
            data: data
    };  

    NativeModules.FileTransfer.upload(obj, (err, res) => {
            console.log(res);   
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fetch() to upload a photo, using mostly the same format you have.

```
var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('photo', {uri: photo_uri_here, name: 'photo', type: 'image/jpg'});
fetch('example.com',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "multipart/form-data",
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            },
            body: formData
        })
```

I don't believe this suffers the same "performance hit" you mention, as I do not believe the transfer is done inside of RN (but correct me if you have already tried this).

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  When I implement using this approach, the uploaded jpg file still contains a multi-part prefix.  And like before, it is no longer recognized as a JPEG file.

Comment: I'm trying to modify your fetch example to avoid multipart.  But so far, I'm only able to upload a zero-byte file...  See update #2 in my original post for the code.